# How to serve a get request in Microsoft Bot Framework?

Tags: node.js, botframework

I am not able to find a way to access/edit user data in response to a request by another server in node.js.

My particular use case involves updating some values for a particular user with the values that the server sends. The server currently has the conversation address stored with it for all users.

Also, I plan to implement serving GET requests to the same server provided I am able to access the data.

Answer (score 1):

To access any conversations BotState you need 2 pieces of information. First you need the channelId, second you need the conversationId.

I don't know where you are performing this logic so I'm going presume this happens in the MessageController and that you have already parsed the 2 id's

```
var channelId = //Parse channel ID => "Skype", "Slack", ...
var conversationId = //Parse conversationId

var stateClient = activity.GetStateClient(); //activity is of type Activity.
var conversationData = stateClient.BotState.GetConversationData(channelId, conversationId);

//Change data.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is there any way we can make it platform independent?  say every user who uses the bot has a username that is common regardless of platform, and I need to change it when the user changes it on a web-prompt per se. It would make little sense to change it on one platform but not the other.

Comment: All userId's are unique only for that platform. So if you want to do this you will have to create a database which links the username to a userid in a channel. It's not possible to just get a list of all datastores in your stateclient.

Comment: Thanks again. I was going through the snippet more carefully and I guess this will work for .NET, I am looking for a node.js solution.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know of a way of doing this in Node.js. I've mostly been using C# to create my bots. The only way of getting the userdata in Node (that I know of) is through the session object. But you can't specify a user id so you can only work with the data from the user that sends the message.
One way you  might be able to resolve this is by storing the userdata in a database, rather than in the datastore.